# How to receive paremeter on promise.finally after clickOutsideToClose and $mdDialog.hide()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I open an $mdDialog

```
$scope.openDialog = function(){
  $mdDialog
    .show({
      // ...
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      controller: MyDialogController
    })
    .then(function(successData) {
      console.log("Closed as success: " + successData);
      // Closed as success: hidden_from_button
    })
    .catch(function(errorData) {
      console.log("Closed as error: " + errorData);
    })
    .finally(function(closeData) {
      console.log("On every close data: " + closeData);
    });
};

function MyDialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.hide = function(){
    console.log("Close 1");
    $mdDialog.hide('hidden_from_button');
  }
}
```

I want to learn how to send parameters to the `.finally` and `.catch` functions of the `$mdDialog`. Specifically when the dialog is closed with the option `clickOutsideToClose: true`. I can't find a way to do it.

This is the relevant code of my dialog:

```
<md-dialog>
  <md-toolbar>
    <md-button ng-click="hide()">
    </md-button>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-dialog-content>
    <!-- Some more code -->
  </md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

I would like to be able to print the messages:

1. `Closed as success: hidden_from_button` (Which I already did)
2. `Closed as error: data_passed_as_error`
3. `On every close data: data_passed_every_time`

I tried adding to `MyDialogController` the function:

```
$scope.on("$destroy", function(ev) {
  console.log("Close 2");
  ev.preventDefault();
  $mdDialog.cancel('data_passed_as_error');
}
```

But the printed output, from all related `console.log` of that action is:

```
Close 2
Closed as error: undefined
On every close data: undefined
```

Which tells me that the parameter is not being received. Besides that, if I use this fuction, after closing the dialog with `ng-click="hide()"`, the last function is called as well. This is the output of all related `console.log` of clicking on close button:

```
Close 1
Close 2
Closed as success: hidden_from_button
On every close data: undefined
```

I want to handle properly the `$mdDialog` and be able to send data to the different `.finally`, `.then` and `.catch` functions of the promise it creates, without colliding with each other.

**I need to send a special parameter when the user clicks outside the dialog** to the parent controller. How do I do that?

Comment: Promises only return the first success or rejection. Any subsequent successes or rejections are ignored. So the subsequent cancel when the scope is destroyed is ignored. The `.finally` method never exposes data, thus it will always show `undefined`. It appears the $mdDialog rejects with a reason of `undefined` on a click from outside. I would guess that the <kbd>esc</kbd> key also rejects with a reason of `undefined`. I don't see anything in the documentation that would let you specify otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know `.finally` **never** exposes data. I have to find a way to solve this using only `$mdDialog.hide() => .then` and `$mdDialog.cancel() => .catch`, the parameter is still not received. Any workaround?

Comment: Yes but I’m trying to send data back to the parent controller when the user clicks outside the dialog, I know the eay it was closed but I need how an inside variable looked in that moment.